# Applying a function $f$ on subsets of $A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say I have $A = \{1,2,3\}$, and subsets of $A$, $B$ = $\{B ⊂ A :|B| = 2\}$, then B will have all possible subsets with cardinality of 2, and they are $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, and $\{2,3\}$,

Now I have a function $f$, which can take 2 or more inputs but they have to be finite, I want to apply my function $f$ on all subsets of $A$ with size of 2, then sum the result,
For example, my function is $\max$, applying max to all subsets max(1,2), max(1,3), max(2,3), the sum of all my max are $$\max(1,2) +  \max(1,3) + \max(2,3) = 2+3+3 = 8$$

how can I write this? where $A$ and size of subsets can change?
like in another case  $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $B = \{B  \subset A:|B|=3\}$

sum of max applied to all $\{B \subset A : |B| = 3\}$ are max(1,2,3) +  max(1,2,4) +  max(2,3,4) = 3 + 4 + 4 = 11

and so on, I've tried $\sum\max(\{B\subset A:|B|=2\})$, and  I'm 99% sure it's wrong, so how can I write it?

one more thing,

my function max can take many inputs, I want one of them to be constant, for example, I apply max to 3 and the subset {1,2,3}, then max to 3 and the subset {1,2,4}, and max to 3 and the subset {2,3,4}, then take the sum of all max,
which is max(3,1,2,3) + max(3,1,2,4) + max(3,2,3,4) = 3 + 4 + 4 = 11

as a property of max, max(a,b,c)= max(a,max(b,c)),

is it right to write it this way $\sum\max(c,\max(\{B\subset A:|B|=2\})$
where c is my const number?

Comment: Something like $\sum_{B\in\wp_k(A)}\max(B)$ where $\wp(A):=\{B:B\subseteq A\}$ and $\wp_k(A):=\{B\in\wp(A): |B|=k\}$. This for $k=1,2,3,\dots$, whatever you like.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion is almost right: you can use $∑\max[\{B ⊂ A: |B| = 2\}]$. In this case, using parentheses for image of a set with respect to function would be ambiguous, hence brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer $\sum \{\max (B) :B\subset A \land |B|=2\}$ or $\sum_{B\in [A]^2} \max (B)$. Set theorists use $[A]^k$ for the set of k-element subsets of $A$.